# Adding a list of items in a column in a csv file

Tags: csv

I have a list of items `{a,b,c,d}`. What is the best way for that list of items to fit into **one** column in a csv file? I want the list of items to be on the same row.

What I am trying to do is having a list of IDs to associate with one item.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output

Comment: I want to append a list of IDs that is related to a certain item in a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a in a single column, I am doing an alternative approach. I added that will indicate the size of the list. Then appended each items in the list with a comma separating them.